# Firestore Security Rules for specific user that was added in the Firebase console directly

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have this user where I added it directly from the firebase console, hence, it is not in any `user` collection.

Is it possible that only this specific userID can access collections of `orders` and `products`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only one user then you can restrict read access of those collections to that specific UID using the following rule:

```
match /orders/{orderId} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid == "firebase_user_id";
}
```